# Prove divergence of infinite sequence using first principles

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've been trying to solve this problem for the last 3 days with no success, I'm sure I'm missing something important, but can't seem to find what.

I'm trying to prove the sequence $a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^nn+1}{n+2}$ diverges,
using *only* the first principles, meaning I can only use $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

I tried to separate it into two cases - $L\lt0$ and $L\ge0$, but I always reach a dead end, having two variables and no idea how to go on.

Could you help me please?

Thank you!

**TL;DR:**
How to prove the sequence $a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^nn+1}{n+2}$ diverges using only $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$?

EDIT: I'm talking about $a_n$ when ${n\to \infty}$ :)

Comment: Do you mean the sequence $\{a_n\}$?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I was sure I wrote it...

Comment: @FrustratedStudent Then please edit your question as the word "series" is very misleading when you actually meant sequence.

Comment: Edited it right now, I wan't aware of the difference, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series is going to converge then, $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ and that is not the case here.

If you meant sequence...suppose the sequence was convergent.  Then for some N>0 $n>N \implies |a_{n+1} - L| < \epsilon / 2$ and $|a_n - L| < \epsilon / 2$

$|(a_{n+1} - L) - (a_n-L)|<|a_{n+1} - L|+|a_n - L|<\epsilon$

$|a_{n+1} -a_n|<\epsilon$

but $|a_{n+1} -a_n| > 1$ for all $n>1$

Comment: Why would the limit be zero if it was convergent?

Comment: If you mean series and not sequence... $|\Sigma_1^{n+1} a_n - \Sigma_1^{n} a_n| <\epsilon$

Comment: @DougM Apparently the asker meant "sequence"